How to get oriented bounding box of Element in XBim?
I'm using the XBim library to extract information about IFC Furniture and Sanitary Elements. Part of that information is the (2D) outline of elements in space.
Ideally, I'd like to get the convex hull of these elements, but I'd also be fine with just a bounding box that is not XY-aligned. How would I achieve that using XBIM?
I've managed to get all furniture using
using var store = IfcStore.Open(myFile);
var furnitures = store.Instances.OfType<IIfcFurniture>();

but don't know where to go from here.
